# Selenium Web Driver is unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to create a small program to put items into a cart. Its supposed to go the page where the item is located and add it to the cart. Then, all the billing information would be input by using the data in a different java class. Every time I run this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;



public class Supreme {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        driver.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/hats/selassie-beanie/grey");
        WebElement add = driver.findElement(By.name("commit"));
        add.click();

        driver.get("https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout");

        AccountInfo a = new AccountInfo();
        a = a.getAccount();

        WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_name"));
        name.sendKeys(a.getName());

        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("order_email"));
        email.sendKeys(a.getEmail());

        WebElement phone = driver.findElement(By.id("order_tel"));
        phone.sendKeys(a.getPhone());

        WebElement address1 = driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_address"));
        address1.sendKeys(a.getAddress1());

        WebElement address2 = driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_address_2"));
        address2.sendKeys(a.getAddress2());

        WebElement city = driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_city"));
        city.sendKeys(a.getCity());

        WebElement zip = driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_zip"));
        zip.sendKeys(a.getZip());

        Select state = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_state")));
        state.selectByVisibleText(a.getState());

        Select type = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("credit_card_type")));
        type.selectByVisibleText(a.getType());

        WebElement credit = driver.findElement(By.id("credit_card_number"));
        credit.sendKeys(a.getCredit());

        Select creditmonth = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("credit_card_month")));
        creditmonth.selectByVisibleText(a.getExpMonth());

        Select credityear = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("credit_card_year")));
        credityear.selectByVisibleText(a.getExpYear());

        WebElement cvv = driver.findElement(By.id("credit_card_verification_value"));
        cvv.sendKeys(a.getCVV());

        List<WebElement> check = driver.findElements(By.className("iCheck-helper"));
        for(WebElement w : check){
            w.click();
        }

        WebElement process = driver.findElement(By.name("commit"));
        process.click();
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"order_billing_name"}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please import thread and see if it works or not ?

Answer (score 12):

Looks like timing issue to me. After you redirect to checkout, you might want to wait for the elements before interacting. See [Explicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) in documentation.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);// 1 minute 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("order_billing_name")));
driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_name")).sendKeys(a.getName());
```

Comment: Implicit or Explicit wait can be used . Or we can use Thread. sleep(milliseconds) http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 3):

you must check is this element in and IFRAME if yes then first switch into iframe and secondly if by ID is not working then Use Xpath or CSS path can you please share HTML source with me.